# How do I disable UTF-8 in an xterm (or X, really)?

Tags: linux, x11, unicode, xterm

I have a system running Debian unstable where I don't want to have UTF-8 in my xterms (or at all). But I recently discovered that somehow I now have UTF-8 in my xterms and other windows. It might have happened when I last updated it (february 24th), but I didn't notice until about a week ago.

My problem is when using special characters such as "å", "ä", and "ö" in Swedish.

Starting a fresh xterm I can select and paste special characters just fine, but as soon as I paste in a special character from another xterm I get e.g. "Ã¥" instead of "å", and after that some setting in the xterm is changed because after that selecting e.g. "å" and pasting it in the same xterm results in "Ã¥" instead. Writing special characters in the xterm still works fine though.

Starting xclipboard I get strange behavior: if I write "å" in xclipboard, select it, and paste it into an xterm I get "Ã¥". If I write "å" in xclipboard, select it, paste it into the xclipboard window, and then paste it into an xterm, I get "å" in the xterm.

If I select some text with special characters in a browser and Ctrl-C it so that it appears in the xclipboard window, and then select it in xclipboard and paste it into an xterm, I get e.g. "Ã¥" instead of "å".

If I select some text with special characters in a browser and Ctrl-C it so that it appears in the xclipboard window, and then select it in xclipboard and paste it into the xclipboard I get e.g. "Ã¥" instead of "å". But if I select the exact same text again in xclipboard and paste it into either xclipboard or an xterm, I get e.g. "å".

All my locale settings (LANG, LC_CTYPE, LC_NUMERIC etc.) are en_US.ISO-8859-15. LANGUAGE and LC_ALL are unset, though. Setting them to en_US.ISO-8859-15 doesn't solve the issue.

If I want to use an xterm with UTF-8, I have a menu choice that sets LANG=en_US.UTF8 and XTERM_LOCALE=en_US.UTF8 before starting a new xterm, and that has worked fine for many years, but now when investigating these problems I discovered that pasting special characters into the UTF-8 xterm results in "�" characters being printed, and selecting special characters in the UTF-8 xterm and pasting them into a non-UTF-8 xterm results in e.g. "Ã¥" instead of "å".

All of this is weird to me, and I don't know how to troubleshoot it any further.

Using Debian unstable's 6.5.0-5-amd64 kernel.
xterm version is 390-1.
xserver-xorg version is 1:7.7+23
xserver-xorg-core version is 2:21.1.9-1

So the kernel and my packages have of course supported UTF-8 for years, but up until a few weeks ago I wasn't having any problems with selecting and pasting special characters.

I haven't knowingly changed any user or system-wide settings that should have caused this change in behavior (or at all, really; I've just been using the machine without having to do any configuring lately).

So my simple question is: how do I get rid of UTF-8 in my xterms? I don't understand why it's suddenly there.

Now, I have found two things which might work: running "xterm -lc" or "xterm -en en_US.ISO-8859-15", or installing the luit package. Initial tests suggest they might work, but since I haven't had to use them before I'm hoping to find a solution that just makes things closer to how they were before, instead of having to use special arguments to xterm or a filter on all my xterms (which luit is). It seems this should be solvable by just setting the correct locale environment variables but I can't figure out what they are.

So I'm hoping for answers that don't rely on "xterm -lc"/"xterm -en en_US.ISO-8859-15" or installing the luit package, since neither of those have been necessary up until a few weeks ago.

If the solution is to use "xterm -lc"/"xterm -en en_US.ISO-8859-15" or installing the luit package, I'm still hoping someone can explain what changed on my system a few weeks ago which caused this. Did some Debian package change to somehow cause this? Which one? I have a few xterms that have been running since I booted the system and they are also affected, not just the ones started after that last update on Feb. 24th, so perhaps some shared lib changed, but are shared libs reloaded by running xterms when the lib is updated? I thought only xterms started after a lib upgrade would load the new version of the lib.

The machine was last rebooted on new year's eve and X has been running since.

Sorry about the wall of text, but I figured it was best to describe my problem and what I'd tried in some detail instead of just crying out "Argh, my xterm treats special characters weird, please help!".

Comment: You don't "get rid of UTF-8" not without causing you no end of problems. Characters not covered by ISO-8859 are everywhere…

Comment: Well, I've been doing just fine for years with no problems whatsoever, so I'd like to continue having this particular system not using UTF-8. It should be possible.

Comment: It's a known bug with #390, which will be fixed in #391.  Downgrading to #389 is the short-term fix (very few users need this combination, by the way).

Comment: "_pasting special characters into the UTF-8 xterm results in "�" characters being printed_" - typically that's because your selected font doesn't have the necessary character symbols, and "_selecting special characters in the UTF-8 xterm and pasting them into a non-UTF-8 xterm results in e.g. "Ã¥" instead of "å"_" - that would be because your source is UTF-8 but your destination is not

Comment: @Chris Davies: "_that would be because your source is UTF-8 but your destination is not_" - yes, but why are my xterms all of a sudden UTF-8? I don't understand why. My locale settings haven't changed etc. etc. so why are my xterms all of a sudden UTF-8? I'm hoping someone can explain.

Comment: I don't know, which is why it isn't an answer. Just trying to help explain the symptoms

Comment: @Thomas Dickey "_It's a known bug with #390_" - thanks, I didn't know that. I checked Debian's xterm package page and bug list before posting here and didn't see anything mentioned there, and I can't find a bug page for xterm upstream (checked at invisible-island.net). Unfortunately I can't find #389 on ftp.debian.org or archive.debian.org so I can't downgrade (unless I compile it myself), perhaps I'll have to wait for #391 to be released.

Comment: fwiw, that was reported to me directly by Petri Kaukasoina.  The basic issue is that in providing improved character-sets for *display*, I had overlooked *pasting*.  Debian's archives are in ... a state of flux ... due to some ongoing changes for Y2038.  Given that xterm #391 may be ready before they're ready to resume normal operation.